# How to include kafka timestamp value as columns in spark structured streaming?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

I am looking for the solution for adding timestamp value of kafka to my Spark structured streaming schema. I have extracted the value field from kafka and making dataframe. My issue is, I need to get the timestamp field (from kafka) also along with the other columns.

Here is my current code:

```
val kafkaDatademostr = spark
  .readStream 
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers","zzzz.xxx.xxx.xxx.com:9002")
  .option("subscribe","csvstream")
  .load

val interval = kafkaDatademostr.select(col("value").cast("string")).alias("csv")
  .select("csv.*")

val xmlData = interval.selectExpr("split(value,',')[0] as ddd" ,
    "split(value,',')[1] as DFW",
    "split(value,',')[2] as DTG",
    "split(value,',')[3] as CDF",
    "split(value,',')[4] as DFO",
    "split(value,',')[5] as SAD",
    "split(value,',')[6] as DER",
    "split(value,',')[7] as time_for",
    "split(value,',')[8] as fort")
```

How can I get the timestamp from kafka and add as columns along with other columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timestamp is included in the source schema.  Just add a "select timestamp" to get the timestamp like the below.

```
val interval = kafkaDatademostr.select(col("value").cast("string").alias("csv"), col("timestamp")).select("csv.*", "timestamp")
```

Answer (score 1):

At Apache Spark official web page you can find guide: [Structured Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide (Kafka broker version 0.10.0 or higher)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html)

There you can find information about the schema of DataFrame that is loaded from Kafka.

**Each row from Kafka source has following columns:**

- key - message key
- value - message value
- topic - name message topic
- partition - partitions from which that message came from
- offset - offset of the message
- timestamp - timestamp
- timestampType timestamp type

All of above columns are available to query.
In your example you use only `value`, so to get timestamp just need to add `timestamp` to your select statement:

```scala
  val allFields = kafkaDatademostr.selectExpr(
    s"CAST(value AS STRING) AS csv",
    s"CAST(key AS STRING) AS key",
    s"topic as topic",
    s"partition as partition",
    s"offset as offset",
    s"timestamp as timestamp",
    s"timestampType as timestampType"
  )
```

Comment: What if I want to add timestamp to Kafka from Spark instead of the other way around? I didn't find any such guide in the link provided here. Is there any configuration I should check in Kafka or Spark?

Answer (score 0):

In my case of Kafka, I was receiving the values in JSON format. Which contains the actual data along with original Event Time not kafka timestamp. Below is the schema.

```
val mySchema = StructType(Array(
      StructField("time", LongType),
      StructField("close", DoubleType)
    ))
```

In order to use **watermarking** feature of Spark Structured Streaming, I had to cast the **time** field into the timestamp format.

```
val df1 = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)").as[(String)]
      .select(from_json($"value", mySchema).as("data"))
      .select(col("data.time").cast("timestamp").alias("time"),col("data.close"))
```

Now you can use the time field for ***window operation*** as well as ***watermarking*** purpose.

```
import spark.implicits._
val windowedData = df1.withWatermark("time","1 minute")
                      .groupBy(
                          window(col("time"), "1 minute", "30 seconds"),
                          $"close"
                      ).count()
```

I hope this answer clarifies.